# Why ubuntu ignores extension based default app when file is empty?

Tags: default-programs

I've set default application for i.e. .py files.
It works if file isn't empty.
Empty .py files still opens in text editor. I can change default app for it but that changes default app of any other empty files regardless of extension.
Why is that happen? It's so frustrating.

Comment: The type of file is determined by contents, and *empty file* is a type. The extension is really just part of the name, and if contradicts with the *type* (determined by contents), the contents are the default selection choice for POSIX/unix since 1973.  Use `file filename.py` and you'll likely see that it reports as an *empty* file...   (1973 was a long time ago... so it's convention now for any unix like operating system, pre-dating microsoft/msdos etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of file is determined by contents, and *empty* file is a type.

The extension is really just part of the name, and if contradicts with the *type* (determined by contents), the contents are the default selection choice for POSIX/unix since 1973.

Use

`file filename.py`

and you'll likely see that it reports as an *empty* file...

*[1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) was a long time ago... so it's convention now for any unix like operating system, pre-dating microsoft/msdos etc*

Comment: Do you know some way to change that? Only for empty files I would like to determine file tyle from extension

Comment: Sorry I don't.. there are others here how may be capable of answering that question.. start another question asking that.

Comment: Wait. I've made some tests and something seems wrong. test.py and test.txt contains the same "abc" text. `file test.py` and `file test.txt` returns the same, but default app is different.

Comment: If they both contain text "abc" they'll both should respond "ASCII text" I'd assume. Certain script files can appear as 'text' so the extension (part of the filename) would be used in that case I'd expect. You'll have to look at the source code itself for more.

Comment: I've found solution by using mimeopen: https://superuser.com/questions/572011/how-do-i-set-up-preferred-applications-in-nautilus-by-file-extension-rather-tha/573488#573488